# iOS - Navigation Bar Back Button color is subdued

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I'm in the process of updating an older Objective C app to work with iOS 9 and I'm running into a little UI weirdness.  I have a non-translucent Navigation Bar.  My issue is that the Back button is more blue than white.  I would like for the back button to be as clear as the Navigation Bar title. (see attached screenshot)

Here is what I have so far:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.11 green:0.27 blue:0.53 alpha:1.0];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
self.navigationItem.title = @"My Title";
```

[image: Navigation Bar]

My question is how do I get my back button to look like my title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Document

> The tint color to apply to the navigation items and bar button items.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I could have sworn that I had that set.  Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees!